# windows command blocks chef run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a chef recipe with the following code (commented out the alternate code that I tried as well)

```
#execute
# execute 'service-api install' do
#   #command "web-#{node['default']['env']}.cmd" #start /HIGH /b -RedirectStandardOutput chef-serviceoutput.txt
#   command ('powershell -c "start-process web-%s.cmd -RedirectStandardOutput C:\\buildinfo\\service-api\\api\\approot\\chef-serviceoutput.txt"' % node['default']['env'])
#   cwd "C:\\buildinfo\\service-api\\api\\approot"
#   #not_if :timeout => 10, :cwd => 'C:\\buildinfo\\service-api\\api\\approot'
#   end

powershell_script 'service-api install' do
  code <<-EOH
  start-process web-#{node['default']['env']}.cmd -RedirectStandardOutput chef-serviceoutput.txt
  EOH
  cwd "C:\\buildinfo\\service-api\\api\\approot"
end
```

The code essentially changes working directory and runs a .cmd file which starts up a server. Now with start-process , it should open up a new cmd and then run the server there but in the original cmd it exits to  a new line.

When I run this through chef, it (i think) is tracking all child cmd from the process as well and just gets stuck after running this section waiting for server to be killed.

Is there any way to work around it in chef/windows ??

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be installing an actual service instead of trying to fork off background jobs from inside Chef. Check out the [`windows_service` resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_windows_service.html).

Comment: Then you'll need something else to create a separate execution context. There is probably something in PowerShell for this, but the common pattern is to use a Scheduled Task set to execute in 0 seconds.